# C#: ftp upload is successful but dowloaded file is damaged

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm using the code bellow to upload a zip file to to my ftp server:

```
string zipPath = @"d:\files\start.zip";
string ftpPath = ("ftp://######/start.zip");


WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(ftpPath);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("######", "######");

StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(zipPath);
byte[] fileContents = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
sourceStream.Close();
request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

try
{
    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    FtpWebResponse makeFileUploadResponse = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("ftp failed!");
}
```

My zip archive is definitely valid (I can open it and extract it) but when I download the uploaded zip file, I got the error that archive is damaged.

**Update 1**: my source code is from MSDN article:[How to: Upload Files with FTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Why would you need `Unicode.GetBytes()` on binary content? Have you tried `byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(zipPath)` instead?

Comment: It's just based on the MSDN article that I mentioned.

Comment: Yes, but they uploaded a textfile, where UTF8 encoding actually makes sense (but still should have worked if they transfered byte-by-byte). It doesn't seem to make sense to me for binary files like a `.zip` file.

Comment: FTP has a ASCII and Binary Mode.  The default is ASCII,  A zip file need to use Binary Mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should cast request to `FtpWebRequest` (as in that MSDN example)
and then specify request as binary (you're uploading binary file, not text).

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("aa");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.UseBinary = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

I can't say what the problem is but I can provide an alternate solution. You can use [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of [WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string zipPath = @"d:\files\start.zip";
string ftpPath = ("ftp://######/start.zip");
WebClient ftpClient = new WebClient();
ftpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("####", "######");
try{
    ftpClient.UploadFile(ftpPath, WebRequestMethods.Ftp.AppendFile, zipPath);
}
catch(WebException ex){
    MessageBox.Show("ftp failed");
}
```

Comment: I don't know the reason for down vote but your solution works just fine; thanks.